# tar blocksize message

Tags: unix, tar

I'm writing a program which untars a file. While doing `untar` tar command give message

```
$ tar -xf testing_Download.txt1.tar  
Tar: blocksize = 12
```

I tried below

```
$ tar 2>&1 1>/dev/null -xf testing_Download.txt1.tar  
Tar: blocksize = 12
```

Below was command output for tar file which was not present in disk

```
tar 2>&1 1>/dev/null -xf testing_Download.txt12.tar
```

> `tar: cannot open testing_Download.txt12.tar`

I want to know how can I tweak my tar command so that I can identify that `untar` got executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Use the return value of tar.

```
tar -xf testing_Download.txt1.tar &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" = "0" ];
then
    echo "success..."
fi
```

or check if the file is there first:

```
if [ -e testing_Download.txt1.tar ];
then
    tar -xf testing_Download.txt1.tar &>/dev/null
else
    echo "tar file not there"
fi
```

Comment: but this is for checking file is not there. I am not sure but there might be some other cases in which tar can fail. Will the return code help in that case also ? because second case will not work for that.